# async foreach not working properly nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
Async.each(asd, (items, callback) => {
    req.models.aswdf.find({id: items.id}, function (err, result){
          category.push(result[0].asd);
    });
    callback();
    }, (err) => {
        if (err)
            next(err, null);
    });
    return done(null, {displayName: people[0].fullName(),id: people[0].id, email: people[0].email, role: category});
```

i am working with nodejs and i want to implement async for-each. I am passing asd as array of object and calling another method to get data from mysql but it is not working properly it enters the loop and get out of it and call done method.
I want to first execute the loop and the call the done method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Async.each(asd, (items, callback) => {
    req.models.aswdf.find({id: items.id}, function (err, result){
        category.push(result[0].asd);
        callback();
    });
}, (err) => {
    if (err)
        next(err, null);

    return done(null, {displayName: people[0].fullName(),id: people[0].id, email: people[0].email, role: category})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

code written outside async will get executed asynchronously as node runs asynchronously. If you want your `done` function to execute after completion of loop write it after the if condition as mention in answer by Sagar above.

```
Async.each(asd, (items, callback) => {
req.models.aswdf.find({id: items.id}, function (err, result){
      category.push(result[0].asd);
});
callback();
}, (err) => {
    if (err)
        next(err, null);

    return done(null, {displayName: people[0].fullName(),id: people[0].id, email: people[0].email, role: category});
});
```